# Reuse validation as DB constraints

Tags: java, validation, constraints, playframework

I'm using the Play! framework and discovered while writing tests that I can save an invalid model instance, e.g. with invalid values for some instance variables. I guess that's expected behaviour to keep validation and persistence separated. But is there any way to reuse the validation annotations as database constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about Play. Do you use JSR 303 validation annotations? According to the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.2/model#hibernate), it can/does use Hibernate for persistence. As of Hibernate 3.5, [Hibernate will include constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#validator-checkconstraints-db) expressed via JSR 303 annotations in the schema it generates.

Comment: I think what you mention is specific to Hibernate, not JPA, but I could be wrong or it could have been disabled by default in Play. Thanks for the though!

Comment: Yes, as I indicated, it's specific to Hibernate 3.5 and later. The Play documentation I linked indicates that Play can or does use Hibernate, so this seems like it should be doable.

Comment: it may be disabled as Play uses JPA (Hibernate as implementation), I'll need to test this evening. I know for a fact that some project I have is not applying them, so probably that's it, this is disabled (or not enabled) by default for compatibility

Comment: My first suspicion would be that it's not using Hibernate 3.5. Otherwise, the property hibernate.validator.apply_to_ddl (true by default) controls this behavior for Hibernate. You might find something by searching for that.

Comment: The more I learn about Hibernate, the more I get the impression that it is not just a beast, but a super-mighty beast. I'm still undecided if I should let fall my intention to only rely on pure JPA and not a specific implementation, but it seems like to rely on Hibernate is a fair trade-off.

Comment: I accepted this as an answer, because I'll take the Hibernate way for now. I intend to write a Play! module that combines validation and database constraints by building on the Hibernate validator.

Answer (score 1):

No, the validation is not linked to database constraints. You have to add the constraints manually in the database via SQL, for example using the new [evolutions](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.1/evolutions) framework of Play 1.2.1.

In your unit tests you must ensure the data you is correct. At any case you should only be testing logic in the Model, no dependencies between classes, just do some tests to check answer to unexpected parameters in places where they could be used but don't worry about instances saved with wrong data.

In your integration tests and selenium tests you should be able to use the Validation system provided by Play via @Valid on controller calls. Here is where you should ensure no objects with bad data are persisted, trying to add some.

Comment: Thanks for the variant using evolutions. For me, testing the validation of a model instance belongs into a unit test, since the logic to determine what is valid and what is not lies in the responsibility of the model. That I tried to save an invalid model in a unit test happened out of pure curiousity - but it broke my mental model. Well, it's fixed again, thanks for that ;)